# How to let the user incorporate a space

Tags: c++

This is a fairly simple question. I want the user to input a genre. In my code, if the user wanted to input "science fiction", it wouldn't print anything. But if I changed the .txt file from "science fiction" and make it one whole word like "sciencefiction" it would print. So, I'm guessing that it has to do with the spacing. How would I make it so that the user can also input two words with spaces. :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

bool compareByTitle(struct Movie m1,struct Movie m2);
void printYear(vector<Movie> &d);
void printGenre(vector<Movie> &d);
void printDirector(vector<Movie> &d);
void printDuration(vector<Movie> &d);
char *capitalize(char* name);
void printAllMovies(vector<Movie> &d);

struct Movie{
        string title;
        string director;
        string genre;
        string year;
        string duration;

    } m;


int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    string line;
    vector<Movie> myMovies;
    char choice, again;

    inputFile.open("Movie_entries.txt");
    while (getline(inputFile, line))   // reads a line from the file
    {
        //cout << line << endl;
        stringstream lineStream(line);   // transforms the line into a stream

        // get fields from the string stream; fields are separated by comma
        getline(lineStream, m.title, ',');
        getline(lineStream, m.director, ',');
        getline(lineStream, m.genre, ',');
        getline(lineStream, m.year, ',');
        getline(lineStream, m.duration, ',');


        myMovies.push_back(m);
    }
    inputFile.close();

sort(myMovies.begin(),myMovies.end(), compareByTitle);


cout << "Please choose on of the following:\n\n"
     << "A - Display all movies listed\n"
     << "B - Display movies in a specific year\n"
     << "C - Display movies in a specific genre\n"
     << "D - Display movies from a specific director\n"
     << "E - Display movies in a specific duration\n"
     << "Enter your choice: ";
     cin >> choice;

//Input validation
while (toupper(choice) != 'A' && toupper(choice) != 'B' && toupper(choice) != 'C' &&
       toupper(choice) != 'D' && toupper(choice) != 'E'){

    cout << "Choice is invalid, the choice must be one of the following: 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' or"
         << " 'E'. \n"
         << "Please try again: ";
    cin >> choice;
}



cout << endl << endl;

switch(choice)
{
    case 'a':
    case 'A': printAllMovies(myMovies); break;
    case 'b':
    case 'B': printYear(myMovies); break;
    case 'c':
    case 'C': printGenre(myMovies); break;
    case 'd':
    case 'D': printDirector(myMovies); break;
    case 'e':
    case 'E': printDuration(myMovies); break;
}


return 0;
}

bool compareByTitle(Movie m1, Movie m2)
{

    return m1.title[0] < m2.title[0];

}

void printAllMovies(vector<Movie> &d)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < d.size(); i++)
    {
    cout << d[i].title << ", " << d[i].director << ", " << d[i].genre << ", "
         << d[i].year << ", " << d[i].duration << endl << endl;
    }
}

void printYear(vector<Movie> &d)
{
    string whatYear;
    cout << "Enter a specific year: ";
    cin >> whatYear;

    for(int i = 0; i < d.size(); i++)
    {
        if(whatYear==d[i].year)
        {


         cout << d[i].title << ", " << d[i].director << ", " << d[i].genre << ", "
             << d[i].year << ", " << d[i].duration << endl << endl;
        }
    }
}

void printGenre(vector<Movie> &d)
 {

    string whatGenre;
    cout << "Enter a specific genre: ";
    getline(cin, whatGenre);
    cin >> whatGenre;

for(int i = 0; i < d.size(); i++)
    {
        if(whatGenre==d[i].genre)
        {
         cout << d[i].title << ", " << d[i].director << ", " << d[i].genre << ", "
              << d[i].year << ", " << d[i].duration << endl << endl;
        }
    }
 }

void printDirector(vector<Movie> &d)
{
    string whatDirector;
    cout << "Enter a specific director: ";
    getline(cin, whatDirector);
    cin >> whatDirector;




    for(int i = 0; i < d.size(); i++)
    {
        if(whatDirector==d[i].director)
        {


         cout << d[i].title << ", " << d[i].director << ", " << d[i].genre << ", "
             << d[i].year << ", " << d[i].duration << endl << endl;
        }
    }
}

void printDuration(vector<Movie> &d)
{
    string whatDuration;
    cout << "Enter a specific duration: ";
    cin >> whatDuration;

    for(int i = 0; i < d.size(); i++)
    {
        if(whatDuration==d[i].duration)
        {


         cout << d[i].title << ", " << d[i].director << ", " << d[i].genre << ", "
             << d[i].year << ", " << d[i].duration << endl << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Insufficient information. Low hanging fruit: Did you read `genre` in using `>>`?

Comment: @user4581301 I just posted my whole code for more clarification

Comment: Off topic: consider replacing `for(int i = 0; i < d.size(); i++)` with `for (Movie & m: d)` and adjust the body of the loop accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

In `void printGenre(vector<Movie> &d)`

```
getline(cin, whatGenre); << reads in genre from user
cin >> whatGenre; << reads in the genre again, but this time only one word of it.
```

A second read of `whatGenre` overwrote the first. Why is this being done? Well... this is why we needed to see more code.

Way back in `main`

```
cin >> choice;
```

read in the a single character. But to get that character, the user had to provide the character and press enter. The enter remained in the input stream, was parsed by

```
getline(cin, whatGenre);
```

and placed the resulting empty string in `whatGenre`.

Be careful flipping back and forth between `>>` and `std::getline`. Preferably use only one.

Solution:

Remove

```
cin >> whatGenre;
```

and replace

```
cin >> choice;
```

with

```
string choicestr;
getline(cin, choicestr);
choice = choicestr[0];
```

or something similar.

You will have to do the same for some of your other functions as well.